# Float formatting with decimals

Tags: ruby

I have a number `charge.amount`, whose value is `1900`. I have a piece of ruby code like this:

```
charge.amount/100.to_f
```

The output is:

```
19.0
```

How do I display it with two decimal points like so:

```
19.00
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sprintf('%.2f', charge.amount/100)
```

Comment: Your solution above works okay, but rounds the hundredth: Like so: 19.01 => 19.00. For my use case, I am getting a block of amounts, some need to display the hundredth of cent.  This seemed to work by extending on your answer: sprintf('%.2f', charge.amount/100.to_f)

Answer (score 1):

The solution above works, but rounds the hundredth. Like so: 19.01 => 19.00

**This works better to include hundredth of a cent:**

```
sprintf('%.2f', charge.amount/100.to_f)
```

Like so => 1901 => 19.01

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, you can use [`number_with_precision`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper/number_with_precision) helper:

```
<%= number_with_precision(charge.amount/100, precision: 2) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use rails helper like:

```
number_with_precision(charge.amount/100, precision: 2)
```